# How to use textup with MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I have the following:

```
$$\frac{5\; \textup{kilometers}}{\textup{hour}}=\frac{10\; \textup{kilometers}}{t}$$
```

but it's rendering like this:

[image]

Is this not supported by MathJax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\textup` is not available in MathJax. You can replace it with `\mathrm`.

Comment: What is "textup" supposed to do anyway?

Comment: It's supposed to produce "upright" text. I would guess it's useful in a context where text would be slanted by default.

Comment: Are you sure `\textup` is a text mode-only command? See [this discussion at TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98407/30726): there it's used in math mode. Or do you mean this statement as specific to MathJax?

Comment: @Ruslan yes turns out textup can be used in both modes, it's just not implemented in MathJax.